# can modsecurity be installed on nginx for windows?

Tags: nginx, mod-security

I have not found any tutorial for the installation of modsecurity in windows, all the ones I find are for linux systems

Does anyone know if it is supported?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the work for ModSecurity on NGINX and Windows is still in progress. See this related GitHub ModSecurity issue named [ModSecurity 3 - Windows Apache/Nginx Connector](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/issues/2480).
Maybe it's worth asking there.